# Batch Operations throwing internal server error (Google Contact API)

Tags: gdata, gdata-api, google-api-java-client, google-contacts-api

We are using [GoogleContact API V3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/). We are getting **internal server error** for the last few days.It was working smoothly a week ago. We implemented exponential backoff to avoid this error, it slow down the process to a greater level and error remains there even after seven minutes of retry using exponential backoff algorithm. Please find the error trace given below:

```
com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException: Internal Server Error
```

Internal Error

```
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:632)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.batch(Service.java:1454)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.batch(GoogleService.java:770)
```

Comment: Hi Munish, did you get any clue? We are also facing same issue.

Comment: seems google fixed this. Is it working fine for you Munish?